# Trying to count number of distinct fields from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in MSSQL;

Videos:
ID,
Artist,
Title

runlog:
videoID,
Datetime

What I'm trying to put together is a result showing:

ID,
Artist,
Title,
times ID played in past 1 hours,
times ID played in past 12 hours,
times ID played in past 24 hours,
times artist played

I have everything except the last column figured out.

```
SELECT ID,Artist,Title,
(select COUNT(*) from runlog where runlog.videoID = videos.id ) as plays,
(select COUNT(*) from runlog where datetime > DATEADD(hh,-1,GETDATE()) and runlog.videoID = videos.id) as hr1plays ,
(select COUNT(*) from runlog where datetime > DATEADD(hh,-12,GETDATE()) and runlog.videoID = videos.id) as hr12plays ,
(select COUNT(*) from runlog where datetime > DATEADD(hh,-24,GETDATE()) and runlog.videoID = videos.id) as day1plays ,

(select COUNT(*) from runlog left join videos on videos.ID = runlog.videoID 
where videos.artist = Artist and runlog.videoID = videos.id) as artistplays 


FROM videos
```

Obviously that last thing just shows the total number of records in the runlog table but I put it to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I've tried to search for a solution first, but I wasn't able to find anything to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and an example of the desired outcome? I'm not sure I understand the requirement.

Comment: What I was lookking for was; Artist, title, num_times_played_in_hour based on a table join. But I'm now looking for a simple list of records from the Videos table, excluding anything that's been played in the runlog table in the given timeframe.   So if a video ID has not been added to the runlog in the past hour, then I want it to show up in the table. If a video from that ARTIST has been played in the past hour, then I don't want ANY of that artists videos to show up in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with aggregation and window functions, combined:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.Artist, v.Title,
       count(rl.videoid) as plays,
       sum(case when datetime > DATEADD(hh, -1 ,GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as hr1plays,
       sum(case when datetime > DATEADD(hh, -12, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as hr12plays,
       sum(case when datetime > DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as hr24plays,
       sum(count(rl.videoid)) over (partition by v.Artist) as artistplays
FROM videos v left outer join
     runlog rl
     on v.id = rl.videoId
group by v.ID, v.Artist, v.Title;
```

Comment: OK! That did exactly what I was asking for! Now I'm seeing that I should have asked for something slightly different. Instead of showing how many times something has played, can I exclude a record from results if it's been played in the past 1hr? 12hrs? or from a particular artist in the past 1hr? 12hrs? and so on?

Comment: So if a video ID has been added to the runlog in the past hour, then I  don't want it to show up in the query. If a video from that ARTIST has been played in the past hour, then I don't want ANY of that artists videos to show up in the query.

Comment: @user3579495 . .  . You can add something like `where  datetime < DATEADD(hh, -1 ,GETDATE())`.  If more complicated than that, you might need to ask another question.

Comment: Thanks, the WHERE DATETIME thing I figured out. I guess, basically what I have left to figure out: if a videoID shows up in the runlog in the past hour, then I don't want ANY other videos from that ARTIST to show up on the Videos query.

Comment: @user3579495 . . . I think you need to explain that as a different question.  I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you mean.

Comment: Posted another question here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331963/exclude-records-from-query-based-on-table-join-results