# Exclude records from query based on table join results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

Videos;
ID,
Artist,
Title

runlog;
VideoID,    'joins to videos.ID
datetime

I'd like to run a query on the Videos table excluding records on three conditions. (as examples. I have multiple conditions, but if I get some help on these, I can probably figure everything else out.

- Any video that shows up in Runlog in the past hour will not show up in the results
- Any Artist that has had a video show up in the runlog in the past hour will not have any other records by the same Artist show up at all in the query
- Any Artist that has had a video show up in the runlog three times in the past 24 hours will not have any other records by the same Artist show up at all in the query

This gets me the first result requirement but I feel it could be written better.

```
    SELECT ID,Artist, Title FROM
    videos join runlog on runlog.videoID = videos.id
    where 
    (select COUNT(*) from runlog where datetime > DATEADD(hh,-12,GETDATE())
    and runlog.videoID = videos.id) = 0 
    order by Artist, Title
```

The second requirement I can't figure out how to put together in the same query.

Comment: Just `AND` them in seprate sub queries in where : for example `Where (subquery1) and (subquery2) and (subquery3)`

Comment: What I want is, if I have a videoID in runlog, I want to query the video table EXCLUDING any records that has an artist matching that video ID.  So, say, if I run videoID 10 which is a video by Madonna, I don't want any other Madonna videos coming up in the Videos query. I don't know how to write a subquery that excludes records from artist after it has to join to find that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query enforces your latter two constraints explicitly and the first implicitly (enforcing the second implicitly enforces the first). It's untested but it should get you on the right track.

```
select ID, Artist, Title
from Video
where Artist not in (
  select V.Artist
  from Video V, Runlog R
  where V.ID = R.VideoID
    and R.datetime > dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())
  union
  select V.Artist
  from Video V, Runlog R
  where V.ID = R.VideoID
    and R.datetime > dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
  group by V.Artist
  having count(*) > 2
);
```

Comment: Better! I don't know what took me so long to sign up for this forum. Thanks so much!

Comment: andrew and @CharlesKiel How is this answer different than mine?

Comment: The one you gave me was giving me duplicates. I have a primary key in my videos table, but I was getting duplicate records with that query. I don't have duplicate records in that database. It had something to do with how it was handling runlog

Comment: Oh, nevermind. They're both giving me duplicates, but I got rid of it by grouping all the fields. Sorry. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this should return duplicates unless there are duplicate rows in the table, but in any case I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT ID, Artist, Title 
  FROM videos v join runlog l on l.videoID = v.id
  WHERE 
       -- 1. All in past hour will not show
       datetime < DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE())
       -- 2. 
       and not exists 
         ( select 1 
           from videos v2 join runlog l2 on l2.videoID = v2.id
           where v2.Artist = v1.Artist and datetime > DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE()) 
       ) 
       -- 3.
       and not exists 
         ( 
           select 1
           from
           (
              select count(1) recordCount
              from videos v3 join runlog l3 on l3.videoID = v3.id
              where v3.Artist = v1.Artist and datetime > DATEADD(hour,-24,GETDATE())
           )
           where recordCount>=3
       ) 
    order by Artist, Title
```

OR

```
  SELECT ID, Artist, Title 
      FROM videos v join runlog l on l.videoID = v.id
      WHERE 
           -- 1. All in past hour will not show
           datetime < DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE())
           and v1.Artist in 
        (
                    -- 2.
            select Artist
            from videos v2 join runlog l2 on l2.videoID = v2.id
            where datetime > DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE())
            union all
                    -- 3.
            select Artist
            from videos v3 join runlog l3 on l3.videoID = v3.id
            where datetime > DATEADD(hour,-24,GETDATE())
            group by v3.Artist having count(1) >= 3
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Artist, Title
FROM Videos V
WHERE V.ARTIST NOT IN
(SELECT V2.Artist
       FROM RunLog R
       INNER JOIN Videos V2 ON V2.ID = R.VideosID
       WHERE dateTime >= DateAdd(hh, -1, GetDate())
 UNION ALL
 SELECT V3.Artist
       FROM RunLog R
       INNER JOIN Videos V3 ON V3.ID = R.VideosID
       WHERE dateTime >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GetDate())
       GROUP BY V3.Artist
       HAVING Count(*) >= 3  
     )
)
```

Same Query can also be done using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT ID, Artist, Title
FROM Videos V
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
       FROM RunLog R
       INNER JOIN Videos V2 ON V2.ID = R.VideosID
       WHERE dateTime >= DateAdd(hh, -1, GetDate())
         AND V2.Artist = V.Artist 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1
       FROM RunLog R
       INNER JOIN Videos V3 ON V3.ID = R.VideosID
       WHERE dateTime >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GetDate())
         AND V3.Artist = V.Artist
       GROUP BY V3.Artist
       HAVING Count(*) >= 3  
     )
)
```

Condition 2 will automatically satisfy Condition 1

Comment: yep! Used the second one.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I appreciate your help @anup-agrawal My only issue now is that i'm getting duplicates in my query results. Why would that be?

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate records in `Videos` table.